# Application crashing in WInXp and WIn2k3 but not in Vista or Win7 after applying KB981793 hot Fix from Microsoft

Tags: c++

I have an existing application developed in VC++ 6.0 which has been installed in many customer sites throughout the world.

This application was working fine until sometime back when the Microsoft KB981793 hot fix was applied. This hotfix has changes related to Timezones and was crashing a crash due to an array overflow in our application code. When this patch was removed the application no longer crashed.

But the interesting thing is this crash was observed only in WinXP and Win2k3 machines and not in Vista or Win7 machines. Any reason why this works this way.

Comment: Could you post a part of your code which leads to the crash? Or maybe minimal sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For XP and 2K3, Microsoft specifies minimum service pack levels as prerequisites.  For Vista and 7 they don't require prerequisites even though service packs exist for Vista.

Comment: Can you be more clear as to how this would prevent the issue from occuring in Vista/Win7

Comment: Your question doesn't say if service packs were installed on the PCs.  If not, then the reason why you got lucky with Vista is that Microsoft didn't set a prerequisite for Vista (even though Vista has service packs they let this hotfix install even without the service packs, on Vista).

Answer (score 1):

KB981793 for XP and 2003 touches Updspapi.dll, KB981793 for Vista or Windows 7 does not. This file is not related to timezones directly, but instead relates to the "setupAPI" (which includes device managament).